# Put linebreaks in a php-string and write everything correctly in MySQL-DB

Tags: php

I try to generate a string with linebreaks, which I want to save in a MySQL-DB

```
//get some data
while($data = $anything->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    $result .= $data->field.'\r\n';
}

$update = $paed_db->prepare('UPDATE table SET anything = :result WHERE id = :id');
$update->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update->bindParam(':result', trim($result), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update->execute();
```

But after reading the result in a textarea, there are no linebreaks but a string which looks like "Lorem\r\nipsum\r\ndolor".

I also tried

```
$update->bindParam(':result', trim(htmlspecialchars($result)), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Already tried that. Same result. Don't understand that...

Comment: maybe the db is doing some auto-escaping of "\" could you have a look ?

Comment: Why has this question been downgraded?

Comment: I didn't downvote but this is the very most basic of PHP and covered extensively in the manual and on SO.

Comment: Perfectly valid question, and one that seems to come up quite a bit based on the activity on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `"\r\n"` (double quotes) since escape sequences aren't interpreted inside of single quotes:

- [PHP Single quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)
- [PHP Double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: Wow. Would never think abou that. Thanks.